# Developing native with ASPI for Win Xp

Tags: c++, windows-xp

I want to develop a C++ application, which will run natively on a Windows XP machine.
It uses the ASPI Drivers to communicate with external SCSI Devices.

The oldest Version on the Microsoft page seems to be VS 2012, which is probably too new.
Which version of Visual Studio do I need to install for coding and compiling natively on Win XP?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 1):

I routinely compile for Windows XP using Visual Studio 2017.

The secret is to install and select the "v141_xp" Platform Toolset in the project's configuration pages (Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset) as described in @drescherjm's link.

I also set the Windows SDK Version to 7.0, although I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have no doubt that your suggestion would work.
In my specific case the software can not be tested in an environment newer than Win XP due to the ASPI drivers.
It has to be coded and compiled on an XP computer.

Comment: Why not build on Windows 10 and test on XP (perhaps in a virtual machine)?